# Is there a way to make my do-while condition to work between intervals?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to get a number that has to be between 13 and 16 numbers using a long, then I needed to convert the long to a string, measure it with strlen and verifying if it's a number between 13 to 16.

My problem is that the condition of the while can't be fulfilled, ever, no matter which number i input

I've tried to change the conditions of the while, tried to measure the lenght of the long by dividing it by 10 using a for loop... Nothing works.

```
long card;
char str[17];
int len;

    do
        {
            card = get_long("Number: ");
            snprintf(str, 17, "%ld", card);
            len = strlen(str)-1;
        } 
        while (len >= 13 || len <=16);
```

Comment: Thank you, but long is storing the numbers correctly, I've debugged it.. I think i just found my problem.. It was so stupid : the while condition was wrong..

Comment: Ah yes, it will loop as long as the number of digits is more than 12 OR less than 17, which is true for any number of digits.

Comment: Do you specifically have to solve the problem this way? `get_long` is a wrapper that reads a line as a string and then scans it as a `long`. Then you're converting it back to a string to check it's length. You'd be better off reading the string and checking its length. Or simply checking if the long is between 10000000000000L and 10000000000000000L.

Comment: The exercise is part of CS50 and they recommended using a long, but the array part is my decision. Many people solved it by dividing the input by 10 in a for loop.

Comment: Per the question, the number input could be negative.  The posted code and the answers do not properly handle such a number

Answer (score 1):

why not just !

```
if(card >= 1000000000000 && card < 10000000000000000){
do_somthing();}
```

Comment: yes, that's a possibility, but since i have measured the string lenght, i thought it could be more "elegant" to solve that other way, but i''m almost adopting your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, a `long` is only guaranteed to contain up to 32 bits or +/- 2,147,483,647. It might fit more, but there's no guarantee. To fit 10**17 you need 64 bits or a `long long`. Alternatively you can use [fixed width integer types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types) like `int64_t` which will map to the appropriate integer type.

The method you're using is a bit tortured. `get_long` is reading the input as a string, turning it into a `long`, and then you're turning it back into a string just to check the length.

Instead, it's simpler and faster to read the line, change it to a number with `sscanf` and check if it's between 1e13 and 1e17.

**UPDATE**: [@user3629249 points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342078/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-do-while-condition-to-work-between-intervals/57342222?noredirect=1#comment101189194_57342222) we have to account for negative numbers. To do so, we take the absolute value with [`llabs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/llabs/).

I don't have CS50 and I'm not a fan; I find its abstractions harmful to learning C. So here it is in conventional C, this is what `get_long_long` is basically doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIGITS13 10000000000000LL
#define DIGITS17 100000000000000000LL

long long card;
long long abs_card;
char line[1024];

do {
    printf("Number: ");
    if( !fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) ) {
        break;
    }
    if( sscanf(line, "%lld", &card) != 1 ) {
        printf("Not a number.\n");
        continue;
    }

    abs_card = llabs(card);
}
while( abs_card < DIGITS13 || DIGITS17 <= abs_card);
```

I've added some macros to make it easier to follow what's happening.

In CS50 it would probably look something like...

```
long long card;
long long abs_card;

#define DIGITS13 10000000000000LL
#define DIGITS17 100000000000000000LL

do {
    card = get_long_long("Number: ");
    abs_card = llabs(card);
} 
while(abs_card < DIGITS13 || DIGITS17 <= abs_card);
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain why you're using a ! in your while condition?

Comment: @GuiVasconcelos You need to find a number between 13 and 16 digits long, so it keeps asking for one until it gets one. It might be better as `while ( card < 10000000000000LL || 10000000000000000LL <= card )`

Comment: this answer still does not properly handle a negative number

Comment: @user3629249 Good point. Easily fixed, take the absolute value. I'll edit momentarily.